# imap_mail_move correct implementation

Tags: php, imap

I'm working with the PHP class [IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) and the function [imap_mail_move](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-move.php) have some **conceptual** problem (which I believe isn't PHP specific), when taking in consideration the available mailbox quota. The problem is that this function moves one message to another folder, flag the original message with a delete flag, and if you want to delete it, you call [imap_expunge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-expunge.php). Ok, so let's suppose I have one mail account with quota (available storage) of 15MB. And I receive one message with 12MB. When I try to imap_mail_move this message to another folder, I get quota limit exceeds, because the function tried to copy the message to the destination folder, exceeding the available limit. Is there any way to get around this problem? I tried to use the function [imap_mail_copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-copy.php), but looks like this function creates a 'mirror' of the original message in another folder, and not actually moves it. When using the imap_mail_copy function with the option: *CP_MOVE* (to delete the message of the current folder after copying), it gives me the exactly same error of imap_mail_move...

I have this code so far (not sure if this matters):

```
        foreach($messagesUID as $messageUID)
        {
            moveMessageToTrash($imapCon, $messageUID);
        }   

        function moveMessageToTrash($imapCon, $UID)
        {
            imap_mail_move($imapCon, $UID, "TRASH", CP_UID);
            imap_expunge($imapCon);
        }
```

Comment: I think there likely isn't a way around this.  IIRC this is a detail of the IMAP implementation where a "move" is explicitly a "copy" followed by a "delete".  You could get around it potentially in a _very_ roundabout way by pulling the data (headers, body, etc) out of the email into the memory of your PHP process, delete the email, then draft a read email in the desired folder with the data you pulled from the original.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but looks like the IMAP doesn't give me the possibility to easily write one message inside some desired folder. So I would need to do something very odd to get this effect. Anyway, thank you for the sugestion.

Comment: /some/ servers support a `MOVE` extension, where you can do `UID MOVE` instead of `UID COPY` which moves a message atomically..  But in the basic specification, move is a COPY + DELETE.  There is no other way to do it.

Comment: `APPEND` is used to write a message into a desired folder.  You could download the entirety of the message, headers and all, delete it, and then `APPEND` it into some other folder.  That'd fix your quota problems, but is a ridiculous amount of bandwidth.

Comment: Good to hear about this append solution, but I think I'll go with the solution to show for the user that he needs to delete some messages first to successfully move others...

Comment: Max do you know what functions should I use to copy headers/body (with attachments, etc)?

Comment: Use whatever FETCH function there is to get `RFC822`, the `FLAGS`, and the `INTERNALDATE`.  This will give you the entire raw text of the message (suitable for appending), and the flags and date you will need to recreate the message as it was.  You should be able to pass all of these to the append function.